# Glyphs signifying "out" and "in"?

Tags: fonts, symbols

How would I "implement" a glyph such as the following:

[image]

to signifty "out", so that I would be able to use it as part of my text without pdftex balking at me?

Specifically, do I need to study the dark voodoo of tikz, or can I make it simpler somehow? Perhaps by combining+stretching a circle and an arrow?

Comment: “What glyph” is off topic. How to implement a particular symbol is on topic.

Comment: @egreg: Edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with TikZ, the measurements are taken as pixels and scaled to the height of an uppercase letter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\circrarr}{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{H}%
    \resizebox{!}{\the\ht0}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
        line width=41pt,
        >={Triangle[length=86pt, width=228pt]},
      ]
        \draw (0, 0) circle[radius=170pt];
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- ++(347pt, 0);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\sffamily A\circrarr B
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Refinements:

- Left and right side bearings
- Some support for italics/slanted.
- Some support for bold.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ItalicAngle}{77}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\circrarr}{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{H}%
    \resizebox{!}{\the\ht0}{%      
      % Italics support
      \let\ItalicShape=N
      \edef\sldefault{\sldefault}%
      \edef\itdefault{\itdefault}%
      \edef\f@shape{\f@shape}%
      \ifx\f@shape\sldefault
        \let\ItalicShape=Y
      \fi
      \ifx\f@shape\itdefault
        \let\ItalicShape=Y
      \fi
      \ifx\ItalicShape Y
        \tikzset{italic/.style={
          transform canvas={xslant=1/tan(\ItalicAngle)}%
        }}%
      \else
        \tikzset{italic/.style={}}%
      \fi
      % Bold support
      \edef\f@series{\f@series}%
      \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series X\@nil
        \def\LineWidth{70pt}%
        \def\TriangleLength{106pt}%
        \def\TriangleWidth{240pt}%
      \else
        \def\LineWidth{41pt}%
        \def\TriangleLength{86pt}%
        \def\TriangleWidth{228pt}%
      \fi
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
        line width=\LineWidth,
        >={Triangle[length=\TriangleLength, width=\TriangleWidth]},
      ]
        \begin{scope}[italic]
          \draw (0, 0) circle[radius=170pt];
          \draw[->] (0, 0) -- ++(306pt + \LineWidth, 0);
        \end{scope}
        \ifx\ItalicShape Y
          \path
            (-170pt - 20.5pt, -170pt - 20.5pt)
            (306pt + \LineWidth, 170pt + 20.5pt)
          ;  
        \fi
        \path % side bearings
          (current bounding box.west) ++(-50pt, 0)
          (current bounding box.east) ++(20pt, 0)
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\sffamily A\circrarr B

{\slshape A\circrarr B}

{\itshape A\circrarr B}

{\bfseries A\circrarr B}

{\bfseries\itshape A\circrarr B}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: So what would happen if I... 1. Use `\textbf`, `\textit` etc? 2. Try to put that in a section header (and hence in the TOC)?

Comment: @einpoklum As usual `\protect` lets fragile commands survive in the section headers. Or the command can be defined with \DeclareRobustCommand.

Comment: Also, I think I'll be changing the dimensions as follows: Triangle length 150pt, rightwards line length 400pt. The arrow looks "smashed" in the image I provided. Probably it makes sense for the circle not to be placed so as to have the same vertical dimensions of a full capital letter; but I wonder if it should be more like `\circ` or more like `\oplus`.

Comment: @einpoklum Feel free to experiment (there is `\raisebox` for shifting vertically, `\vcenter` to center around the math axis, ...).

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't these icons from `fontawesome` be OK? Or you can make your own signs with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage{pstricks, pst-arrow}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\newcommand\ArrowIn{\begin{pspicture}\psset{linejoin =1, fillstyle=solid,, opacity=0.4 }
\pscircle[linewidth=2pt]{0.8ex}\psBigArrow[ fillcolor=Tomato!30, linecolor=Tomato, doublesep=0.3ex](0.75em,-0.1ex)(0,-0.1ex)
\end{pspicture}}
\newcommand\ArrowOut{\begin{pspicture}\psset{linejoin =1, fillstyle=solid,, opacity=0.4 }
\pscircle[linewidth=2pt]{0.8ex}\psBigArrow[ fillcolor=RoyalBlue!30, linecolor=RoyalBlue, doublesep=0.3ex](0,0.1ex)(0.75em,0.1ex)
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\Huge A \faSignIn \,\,B\,\,\faSignOut \,\,C

A\ArrowOut B\ArrowIn C

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Huh. Hmm. Hmph. That's not so bad. I mean, they don't "scream" the message as well as the image I linked to but it might do. So +1 but not accept. Another deficiency of these is that the arrows don't like the stroke of a font, but like the blot of a stamp.

Comment: @einpoklum, You cut me to the quickk. I've added a more ‘screaming’  `pstricks` solution.

Comment: My dear Bernard... this question asks for a glyph, not a neon sign :-)

Comment: You always can remove colouring; or use another shade of gray.